find the first TRUE within a group
I want to save the position of the first TRUE in level variable within each id. I am doing the below:
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(first_true = min(which(data$level == TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup()

However, the result for first_true is the same for all id. group_by(id) is not working. Any idea of what might be happening?
Example data:
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
level <- c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
data <- data.frame(id, level)
data$level <- as.logical(data$level)

I would like to obtain:
id level
1 0
1 0
1 0
2 2
2 2
2 2 
3 1
3 1
3 1


It's hard to say without actual data, but it seems like you could filter for rows where level is TRUE and then get the first value for each id data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(level) %>% slice_head(n = 1)

Please provide a reproducible example and the corresponding expected output. Also: what value do you want in case where there is no TRUE for an id?

Thanks both, I've added a reproducible example. I would like to understand why my code using mutate does not work in this case, do you know?

Your code does not work because the mutate references data$level, which is the original data set outside of the dplyr chain (it has no awareness of grouping). Within mutate, you should just reference level without the data$ prefix, which is what dplyr expects. With that fixed, your code will print a warning because some groups have no TRUE values for min to use, but it will run and produce the expected result.

You can try
data %>%
    mutate(first_true = ifelse(any(level), min(which(level)), 0), .by = id)

which gives
  id level first_true
1  1 FALSE          0
2  1 FALSE          0
3  1 FALSE          0
4  2 FALSE          2
5  2  TRUE          2
6  2  TRUE          2
7  3  TRUE          1
8  3  TRUE          1
9  3  TRUE          1


If I understand you correctly, you could use summarize and which:
Data
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:5, each = 3),
                   level = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 15, replace = TRUE))

Code
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  summarize(position = which(level)[1], .by = id)

#   id position
# 1  1        1
# 2  2        2
# 3  3        3
# 4  4        1
# 5  5        2

You could also do data %>% reframe(position = which(level)[1], .by = id).
Note this will return NA for id values that contain all FALSE values.
If you wanted to keep all the data without losing any rows, you could use reframe or mutate:
data %>%
  reframe(level = level,
          position = which(level)[1], 
          .by = id)

#    id level position
# 1   1  TRUE        1
# 2   1  TRUE        1
# 3   1  TRUE        1
# 4   2 FALSE        2
# 5   2  TRUE        2
# 6   2 FALSE        2
# 7   3 FALSE        3
# 8   3 FALSE        3
# 9   3  TRUE        3
# 10  4  TRUE        1
# 11  4 FALSE        1
# 12  4 FALSE        1
# 13  5 FALSE        2
# 14  5  TRUE        2
# 15  5 FALSE        2

EDIT
Using the newly supplied data and desired output in the recent question edit, you could replace the NA values with 0 using tidyr::replace_na():
data %>%
  mutate(position = which(level)[1], .by = id) %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(position = 0))

Though I personally believe the answer provided by @ThomasIsCoding is more elegant.

@Daniela glad it was helpful. I dont know what you mean by 'does not give the correct answer' (i.e., did you get an error? unexpected results? Your edit was helpful in showing that you want 0 instead of NA's when there are no TRUE values - Ive edited to address this. Let me know if thats not what you mean!

You didn't provide data for us to reproduce your question, but here I've provided something that should fit to your description:
data <- tribble(~id, ~level,
        1,   FALSE,
        1,   FALSE,
        1,   TRUE,
        1,   FALSE,
        2,   FALSE,
        2,   FALSE,
        2,   TRUE,
        2,   TRUE,
        3,   FALSE,
        3,   TRUE,
        3,   TRUE,
        3,   FALSE
)

In this example, we create a column with the position of each TRUE value, and later, we create another column with the smaller position of TRUE values for each id.
result <- data |> 
  # add row numberd for each id
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(position = row_number()) |> 
  # create column with the position of each TRUE value
  mutate(true_position = ifelse(level == TRUE, position, NA)) |> 
  # create another column with the smaller position of each TRUE value
  mutate(min_position = min(true_position, na.rm = TRUE))

You can also filter to get only the first TRUE of each group:
result |>
  group_by(id) |> 
  filter(true_position == min(true_position, na.rm = TRUE))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Groups:   id [3]
     id level position true_position min_position
  <dbl> <lgl>    <int>         <int>        <int>
1     1 TRUE         3             3            3
2     2 TRUE         3             3            3
3     3 TRUE         2             2            2


Or just data |> mutate(first_true = ifelse(any(level), which.max(level), NA), .by = id)?

@Axeman sure, there are millions of ways of doing it. I just tried to provide one that is clearer to a beginner user, following a step-by-step approach.
